# Is it possible to cut a circle and make smaller circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Recently I saw this meme:

[image]

Although the pizza hasn't completely the shape of a circle, let's say we have a circle is it possible to cut a part of the circle like this in the image and make smaller circle? If yes, how many circles  (with different radius) can we make?

Comment: No it's not. A circle of radius $r$ has a fixed curvature. Really, the smaller pizza is a football shape.

Comment: You can calculate the area of the original pizza given any fragment of its rim that contains more than three points. So there is no way of making a finite number of cuts that leaves a circular remainder.

Comment: ... I meant "at least three points", but that doesn't make any relevant difference. (@900edges: you should perhaps clarify that you mean an American or Rugby football $\ddot{\smile}$)

Comment: @RobArthan Good point, I forget a football is round to the majority of the world!